# What is the powershell equivalent for `pwd -P`?

Tags: powershell

I have made a symlink using `cmd /c mklink /D "MyDir" C:\MyDir` in my home directory C:\Users\myusername. When I type `cd toDir` from my homedir and type `pwd` it returns

```
Path
----
C:\Users\myusername\My Dir
```

How can I return the "physical" path of the directory like with unix's `pwd -P`?

Comment: Hello, I don't understand exactly what you mean. Do you just want to fin the PowerShell equivalent to pwd ? If so, it's simply Get-Location.

Comment: Hi. Under powershell `pwd` is an alias for Get-Location. AFAIK it cannot display the real/physical path you are in after changing directory to a symlinked directory, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The "easy" way is to use `Get-ReparsePoint` from [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com/)

`Get-Location` or `pwd` will not be useful on its own

To detect a reparsepoint check the Attributes on the Item

```
((Get-Item $PWD).Attributes -band [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint) -ne 0
```

Actually getting the target without [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com/), is annoying and requires the .NET API as described in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240734/c-sharp-how-to-retreive-the-target-of-a-junction-or-symlink-with-a-standard-us)